# HTML form with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm making HTML form(sign up), I have tipical fields/inputs(username, password, e-mail etc...). My plan is to push whole HTML form into other .php file(with POST method). Second .php file will do MySQL part(put user into MySQL base...). But sign up contains parts that I need push into other .php file, only problem is - these parts aren't in HTML form.
So, I have part in which user can select skin. User on sign up(when page loads) get random skin ID. For ID I use PHP var(eg. $var;). When user click on skin image, it'll call jQuery function.
I'm not sure how to chage value for PHP var later(I think it's 
impossibly), and I don't Know how to push "non-HTML-form" values into other .php file. Thanks!

**@ EDIT: Video is [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=21FED1D2B527179E!468331&authkey=!AFvDWniFblH4UD4&ithint=video%2Cmp4)**

**@ EDIT 2:** Code is [here](http://pastebin.com/weMvekwd)

Comment: please be more precise. give some examples, some lines from your your code, what you get when executing them etc.

Comment: do some code and then ask a specific question, not a question in general, without anything done.

Comment: I did some code, but I can't go forward because I don't Know how chage value in PHP var. I'll paste video in next five minutes.
@ I have code, it's too big. Actually, I'm not sure which part of code I should paste here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can easily use hidden fields and send OR post data using ajax you have to use form submit method OR ajax call for posting data.
https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
<!-- this your simple html form with all data that user inputs -->
<form onsubmit="javascript: return false;">
    <input type="text" value="" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
    <!-- You can easily pass hidden values using type="hidden" -->
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="10" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>

<!-- Now you can post all serialized data one to another file -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("form").submit(function(event) {
   var data = $(this).serialize();
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "yourfile.php",
     data: data,
     success: function(response){
         alert(JSON.stringify(response));
     }
   });
   event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You have to save skin to hidden field in form when page loads,
if user change skin you have to update that hidden field via jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use an `<input type="hidden" />` and set the value of that hidden field in your javascript code so it gets posted with your other form data.

Comment: Thanks for help!
I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I mean that when the user selects a skin, you change the value of that hidden input (that will be used only to contain the chosen value of skin) and then when you post the form, you send that value alongside with other form inputs!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
data:  $("form#a").serialize(),...`.A hidden input type field with lets say having an id of 'skin' will be set to the id of the skin clicked on the popup that you showed in the above video.Then send the form values using the jquery ajax method serialize() and you will get the form values as well as the skin id from the popup in the php file that you would have wanted to send